# How to send a request to Google Authorization Server

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I am trying to get access token for Google Calendars API.
But I don't know how to communicate/send a request to **Google Authorization Server**.

Is there any endpoint for that? I've read the documentation and this is where I've got stuck!
I am using java in my android app

I've used [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) but don't know how to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

Check the code shown in the [Java Calendar Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java), which helps you to call the Google Calendar API.

You could also check the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) and the [Google OAuth Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/), which show you how to call any Google API and handle the OAuth process respectevely using Java.

Comment: At this time I am using Postman because I want to understand how this thing works..!

Comment: It looks like it doesn't want to work ;/
It says the credentials.json couldn't be found but I have added it !

Comment: put your credentials.json file in your resources folder

Comment: Look I finally did it and got my account token. But I have another problem now. After user going to the url and accepts the scope, A Specific(that i've typed) URL is hit with some information(code) passed as parameters. The problem is that I only get the code without the user's email. So there is no point storing it in my database and the ask for the access token!

Comment: I recommend you to check [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). You use that code to exchange it for the Access Token

Comment: That is not what I said. I know that I have to exchange it for an Access Token!